# Downloading Images using AlamoFireImages

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am trying to download my images to my table view on the home page for a project. I have retrieved the URLs from the API and they are valid (Printed in terminal)

I am then dumping these URLs into an array `let imageURL = [String]()`

I looped through the urls and requested the images through the `AlamofireImage`, but they are not get displayed

```
         for url in self.imagesURL {
                    ItemImages.removeAll()
                    Alamofire.request(url).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        guard let image = response.result.value else {return}
                        self.ItemImages.append(image)
                        completed(true)
                    })
                }
```

next I am looking to convert these urls into images to be displayed..If someone could help me on where to move forward next that would be great.Or if I am going wrong anywhere...

Comment: have you tried dumping the response before your `guard` statement to see whats happening? `dump(response)` - you might be.. enlightened.

Comment: Also don't forget you can use breakpoints to pause and inspect variables during runtime. checkout the [Debugging tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

Comment: if you add some print statements right before `self.ItemImages.append` does it get printed? (or use debugging tools to ensure it actually happens)